# TIFFSetField warning (unknown tag) when adding custom fields

Tags: c++, tiff

I am creating a GeoTIFF and use the following code which seems to work fine, but the library generates a lot of warnings, specifically about the custom fields I am trying to add. Can anybody point out why this is the case or what I am doing wrong?

The warnings are specifically: `TIFFSetField: [filename]: Unknown tag 34264` and `TIFFSetField: [filename]: Unknown tag 34736`

```
#define TIFFTAG_GEOTRANSMATRIX  34264
#define TIFFTAG_GEOKEYDIRECTORY 34735
#define TIFFTAG_GEODOUBLEPARAMS 34736

TIFF* tif = TIFFOpen(filename.c_str(), "w");
if (!tif) throw std::runtime_error("Error creating TIFF object");

// Add custom tags
// [enum, read count, write count, type, bit, ok to change, pass count, name]
// -1 for read count/write count signifies variable length
const TIFFFieldInfo xtiffFieldInfo[] = {
    { TIFFTAG_GEOTRANSMATRIX,  -1, -1, TIFF_DOUBLE, FIELD_CUSTOM, 1, 1, (char*)"GeoTransformationMatrix" },
    { TIFFTAG_GEOKEYDIRECTORY, -1, -1, TIFF_SHORT,  FIELD_CUSTOM, 1, 1, (char*)"GeoKeyDirectory" },
    { TIFFTAG_GEODOUBLEPARAMS, -1, -1, TIFF_DOUBLE, FIELD_CUSTOM, 1, 1, (char*)"GeoDoubleParams" },
};
TIFFMergeFieldInfo(tif, xtiffFieldInfo, 3); // manually set 3 for testing

TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_GEOTRANSMATRIX,    16, &xform[0]); // <- generates warning
{
    const Float64 tmp[2] = { 298.257223563, // GeogInvFlatteningGeoKey
                             6378137.0 };   // GeogSemiMajorAxisGeoKey; WGS 84 reference ellipsoid defines 6,378,137m
    TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_GEODOUBLEPARAMS, 2, &tmp[0]); // <- generates warning
}

// Write a few other tags and image scanlines

TIFFClose(tif);
```

Comment: Huh? Setting tag 34264 generates an error saying tag 34266 is unknown?

Comment: that was a typo